# Custom PictureBox Control

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, user-controls

Could someone please show me a example of how to create a custom control based on a picturebox?

I just want this: If the picturebox gets clicked (`OnKeyDown`) the image should be moved by 3 pixels down and 3px to the right. Afterwards at an `OnKeyUp` event I want to restore the original image.

Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: what are you using for your platform? silverlight? wpf? asp.net? win-forms? etc.  you will get a better answer.

Comment: i added the winforms tag for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Gets clicked" is `OnMouseX`, not `OnKeyX`.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : PictureBox 
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool shifted = false;

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && this.Image != null)
        {
            this.shifted = true;
            this.Invalidate();
        }

        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && this.Image != null)
        {
            this.shifted = false;
            this.Invalidate();
        }

        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        if (this.shifted)
        {
            pe.Graphics.TranslateTransform(3, 3, System.Drawing.Drawing2D.MatrixOrder.Append);
        }

        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for this solution. just one problem: when clicking on the picturebox the original image is somehow resized (=> a lot smaller).

Comment: @nr1 You probably set a stretching mode which isn't respected in this example. Try with no stretching. I was only to show how to do this kind of thing in principle. You can easily add support for stretching modes.

Comment: @nr1 On a second thought, I think it'd be better to amend my code. See the edit.

Comment: yes thx for your help. unfortunately i have no stretching mode set but somehow the image is always drawn a lot smaller than original.

Comment: @nr1 Even with the new version?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old post but I have found it and was very usefull.
But I spent about one working day with solving an issue that my DrawRectangle was drawn below image that I loaded.
The solution was to move `base.OnPaint(pe);` method on the begining of `OnPaint` method.

Hope this helps.

**Adam**